# Why Won't my computer turn on?

Tags: boot, bios, power-management

Yes, as dumb of a question as it is. This is the only place I knew of to get a fast answer.

Pressing the power button does nothing. Power cord connected and circuit is getting power. If I flip the off switch on the power supply and unplug the cord for about 10 minutes, then plug it back in and, turn on the power supply, then push the power button on the front. It starts to turn on for 2 seconds, but shuts off and never gets to the BIOS and never even turns the monitor on.

Is this a bad power supply? Or is it some other issue? I was thinking the power supply, but don't want to buy a new one to only find out its not the problem.

P.S. This is Ubuntu related mainly because I use nothing but GNU/Linux Operating systems :-D And will most likely be doing a fresh install of 12.04 once its working again!!!

Comment: If you can't even get to the BIOS then it sounds like you have a hardware problem, sorry. :(

Comment: Is the CPU fan still attached and working? Does the computer make any beeping noises? This may indicate that RAM is not seated.

Comment: Yup, thought odd you mention that, cause a few months before this started, I opened it up and cleaned out all the dust. Took the CPU Heat Sink off, clean of every spec of dust, and put new Thermal Paste on it.(good stuff, not cheap) and put it all back together and was working great for a long time.                                                         Oh and @JorgeCastro , I'm also pretty sure its a hardware problem. My only delima is finding out what part is going bad. Not an easy thing to find. :(

Comment: Sounds like a faulty power supply, any chance you could swap one with a friend to test? It's the easiest way to rule it out, you could know for sure if you take some measurements, but you'd need to know a bit about electricity and have, at the very least, a multimeter.

Comment: First of all make sure your power supply is working when apart of your MB, remove it from the case and produce a short circuit in the green and black cables (black will be better the one beside the green but it can be any indeed), you can achieve this with a paper clip. Here is a video on how to test it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0OKmIuNtmI and here is a more comprehensive explanation about how and what to test in a power supply: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKoctd4ReW8&feature=related If the power source is working fine, then you can consider a different fault. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @GeppettvsD'Constanzo!! I'll try that later tonight. And roadmr, I actually was a Union Electrician Apprentice for 3 years. So I've got moderate experience in electrical work. And bout 3 multimeters round here. What do you suggest? Similar to Geppettvs D'Constanzo 's suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with other comments that this looks like a *hardware fault*.

Given that you can sometimes power in for 2 seconds before it may be time to breakout the manual for the mother board of PC/Laptop.

If you get the model name and number of your motherboard you can try to get support from the manufacturer and/or research on Google to see if other customers have had similar issues.

**Best of luck with it!**

Comment: Thank you @Rob. Though this is a pre-built machine from Medion. And I'm pretty sure the maunals that came with it didn't have any Mo.Bo. information. But in the first screen on booting normally it says American Trends I think. Is there a site that I can just look up that MoBo manufacuter?

Comment: Probably best bet contact Medion quoting the laptop or pc model number see what they say.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply. But I just did try to find the contact info. And they only offer Email support. Which would be fine. But they require my full home address and and phone number, even though it will only be a Email conversation. I just have a policy of never giving out more info than is really needed. But I did do they test someone else described with the paper clip to by pass the power switch. And nothing happened at all. So I'll be looking for the best deal on PSU's when I have the money. Thank you all!!! God Bless